# How to read initial properties in React Native

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I am passing initial properties onto my React Native application.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"testID": @"123"};
```

This is received on the React Native side, and it displays

```
{"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{"testID":"123"}}.
```

However, I am reading the data on React Native side as -

```
componentWillMount() {
  var token = this.props.testID;
  console.log("testID is " + token);
}
```

**It gives error JSON value NSNull cannot be converted into NSString.**

**testID is undefined**

Comment: Is the code snippet `@{"testID": @"123"}` correct? There should be an `@` sign before the `"testID"` literal.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@` in your dictionary. Consider the following example to pass initial props:

```
NSArray *imageList = @[@"http://foo.com/bar1.png",
                       @"http://foo.com/bar2.png"];

NSDictionary *props = @{@"images" : imageList};

RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                             moduleName:@"ImageBrowserApp"
                                             initialProperties:props];
```

You can read more in [communication-ios](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html#properties) section.